# Make table stretch with div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RvSK5/
Try resizing the window...

How can I make a table to `stretch` and `shrink` always to the 100% width and height of parent element.

If we shrink the div to very small sizes the `<p>` prevent the table from shrinking. How can I fix this?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `width: 100%;` for your table? See http://jsfiddle.net/RvSK5/1/

Comment: When the div get's really small the table jumps outside the div!

Comment: Then you should use `width: 100%; min-width: 20em; /* or whatever */`

Answer (score 1):

In your example the text in the paragraphs is preventing the table cells from shrinking to the width of the parent div. Assuming the parent div can be wider, just add `width: 100%` to the table.

```
#table{
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RvSK5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
#test{
    width:10%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
}

#table{
    border: 1px solid green;
    width:100%; /* Make the width 100% of the parent */
}
```

If you want to get some more insight, I recomend reading http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Comment: If you mean zooming in and out, I suppose the only way to do that is via the **transform** or **zoom** css properties, controlled by a script.

Answer (score 0):

see you have to give 100% width and height to the table to make it stretch to its parent div height and width [check out this link](http://ddle.net/RvSK5/4/)